# Snap SVG animation doesn't reset on state change

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, snap.svg

(SVG has been simplified for the sake of brevity)

I'm experiencing a problem with an SVG animation that is executed on hover, and then animates back to its initial state on hover release. The animation executes fine, but the issue arises when the user only hovers briefly over the element, as the hover animation still executes, but the reset-animation starts executing at the same time, causing some elements of the SVG to be in hover state, and others to be in hover-release state.

Essentially, what I want to do, is to stop the animation from executing and animate back to the initial state if the hover is released before the animation has executed fully.

This is my JavaScript as of now:

```
var newSvg = '';        

var s = Snap("#svg-container");

Snap.load('http://pathtofile.svg', function (f) {
    var g = f.selectAll('g');
    s.append(g);
    newSvg = s.group(s.selectAll('g'));
});

$('#container').mouseenter(function() {
    newSvg.stop();
    animate();
});
$('#container').mouseleave(function() {
    newSvg.stop();
    reset();
});


function animate() {
    newSvg.select('.screen-inner').animate({
        fill: '#d5e2af'
    }, 200);
    newSvg.select('.content-circles').attr({
        opacity: '1',
        fill: 'transparent',
        stroke: '#dda7d2'
    });
    newSvg.select('.circle-1').animate({
        'stroke-dashoffset': '0',
        opacity: '1'
    }, 450, mina.easeout);
    newSvg.select('.circle-2').animate({
        'stroke-dashoffset': '0',
        opacity: '1'
    }, 450, mina.easeout);
    newSvg.select('.circle-3').animate({
        'stroke-dashoffset': '0',
        opacity: '1'
    }, 450, mina.easeout);
}

function reset() {   
    newSvg.select('.screen-inner').animate({
        fill: '#222426'
    }, 200);     
    newSvg.select( '.circle-2' ).animate({
        'stroke-dashoffset': '44',
        'opacity': '0'
    }, 125);
    newSvg.select( '.circle-1' ).animate({
        'stroke-dashoffset': '44',
        'opacity': '0'
    }, 125);
    newSvg.select( '.circle-3' ).animate({
        'stroke-dashoffset': '44',
        'opacity': '0'
    }, 125);
}
```

I have experimented with Snap's stop()-function and jQuery stop()- and clearQueue()-functions, but with no luck.

The (simplified) SVG looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 300 300" style="enable-background:new 0 0 300 300;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st1{fill:#B3B3B3;}
    .st3{fill:none;stroke:#B3B3B3;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .screen-inner{fill:#222426}
</style>
<g class="full">
    <g class="screen-inner" fill="#222426">
        <rect x="38.4" y="76.2" class="st0" width="222.4" height="111.2" />
        <path class="st1" d="M260.3,76.7V187H38.9V76.7H260.3 M261.3,75.7H37.9V188h223.4V75.7L261.3,75.7z"></path>
    </g>
    <g class="content-circles">
        <circle class="st3 circle-1" opacity="0" stroke-width="14px" stroke-dasharray="44" stroke-dashoffset="44" cx="92.8" cy="125" r="7" />
        <circle class="st3 circle-2" opacity="0" stroke-width="14px" stroke-dasharray="44" stroke-dashoffset="44" cx="149.6" cy="125" r="7" />
        <circle class="st3 circle-3" opacity="0" stroke-width="14px" stroke-dasharray="44" stroke-dashoffset="44" cx="206.2" cy="125" r="7" />
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Is there a solution to this issue?

Comment: Could you include the code with Snaps stop() method that you tried, as that would be the first way I would try, and wondering if that was used incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, hereby updates in the animate() and reset() functions

Comment: Your stop command is being applied to a group which has no animation applied to it, try adding it to the specific elements being animated, eg newSvg.select('.screen-inner').stop().animate({ ... })